# SPARK to ELASTIC SEARCH program throwing exception, Append output mode not supported

Tags: scala, apache-spark, elasticsearch, apache-kafka

l am running the following code on windows its throwing an error and not working . zk,kafka,elasticsearch all server are running though. data is already published to the kafka topic

```
  object kses {
      def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {


  val spark = SparkSession.builder.
    master("local")
    .appName("sparkToES")
    .config("es.nodes", "localhost")
     .config("es.index.auto.create","true")
     .getOrCreate()



  import spark.implicits._

  spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")

  val df = spark
    .readStream
    .format("kafka")
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
    .option("subscribe", "logi1")
    .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
    .load()

  val data = df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")
    .as[(String, String)]

  val results = data
    .map(_._2)
    .flatMap(value => value.split("\\s+"))
    .groupByKey(_.toLowerCase)
    .count()

    val query = results.writeStream

      .format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql")
      .outputMode("append")
      .option("es.nodes", "localhost")
      .option("es.port", "9200")
      .option("es.nodes.discovery", "true")
      .option("es.http.timeout", "20s")
      .option("es.http.retries", "0")
      .option("es.resource","logi123")
      .option("checkpointLocation", "~/checkpoint_es")
      .start()

  query.awaitTermination()

}

}


  ERROR - Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Append output mode not supported when there are streaming aggregations on streaming DataFrames/DataSets without watermark;

When i change it to 'complete' mode then also code doesnot run.
```

zk,kafka,elasticsearch all server are running though.

Answer (score 0):

ElasticSearch Resource path in Save() should be the path of the Index Resource on the ES node not your local path.

Check the connectivity of the ES node and provide the valid Index (for ex: "index/persons") path in Save() method.

```
df.write.format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql").option("es.nodes.wan.only","true")
.option("es.port","9200")
.option("es.net.ssl","true")
.option("es.nodes","192.168.0.1")
.mode("append")
.option("es.nodes.client.only", "false")
.save(<Index Resource PATH>)
```